# Should dependencies in UML have multiplicities shown

Tags: uml

I know a dependency relationship is depicted using a striped arrow e.g.:

```
Client -----<<create>>----> Server
```

I see that multiplicity is typically needed for other relationships (association, composition, aggregation) however, I'm unsure if it's needed or required for a dependency relationship. Should I put a '1' on each side of the above diagram?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no point in multiplicity on a dependency. Dependency merely states that a classifier (usually a class) in some way depends on another classifier. There is no way to say you depend on specific amount of those other classifiers since it doesn't touch the instances level.

In the UML specification (Section 7.5.1.) we have:

> Types and multiplicity are used in the declaration of Elements that contain values, in order to constrain the kind and number of values that may be contained.

As association (including its stronger versions shared and composite aggregation) is semantically equivalent to a classifier's feature it support multiplicity. But this is not applicable to dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Of the types of relationships in Class diagrams, multiplicity doesn’t apply to generalisations and realisations. You can apply multiplicity to dependencies but it often is not useful to do so, since dependencies are about how changes to one thing impact another.